# How to write "If player gets +1" in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

So the code im adding, is, when a 'player' gets + 1 'gold' (you get gold for killing monsters like around every 5-10 monsters)

I dont know how to make it say if player gets + 1 gold, all i have is

```
    private void GoldNotification(int Gold)
    {
        Gold = Client.Player.Gold;

        if (Gold != -1 && Client.Player.Gold != Gold)
        //then here im going to add code for it to display a notification that says +1 Gold above your character for a brief few seconds just so people know when they gain gold
    }
```

just focus on the

```
    if (Gold != -1 && Client.Player.Gold != Gold)
```

because thats all im really questioning about, i get 0 errors in VS but when i test it in-game, it doesnt work.

Comment: You have 2 golds in your code...you pass an int name gold, then you set its value...is this on purpose

Comment: What value is passed to this method as a parameter value? It this the current amount of player's gold? If this is so, you possibly can't compare current amount of gold to current amount of gold (or rather, you can compare but you won't make anything of it).

Comment: You are overwriting `Client.Player.Gold` on `Gold`, but the if clause is asking for those two values to be different `!=`, so you never enter inside that block of code

Comment: Do you mean +1 gold as in the state of the property `Gold` changed by +1, or do you mean that `Gold` is +1 or higher? Hard to tell by reading your code alone....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to keep the original value before checking and then add gold to player.

```
private void GoldNotification(int Gold)
{
    //Gold = Client.Player.Gold; // remove this

    if (Gold != -1 && Client.Player.Gold != Gold + Client.Player.Gold) // after this check add gold to player
    {
        Client.Player.Gold += Gold;
        //...
    }
}
```

in this part `Client.Player.Gold != Gold + Client.Player.Gold` if Gold is `0` the condition becomes false means no gold added

Edit : I am so stupid. this can be simplified to

```
if (Gold > 0)
```

That means gold is more than 0 so sure we added this to player.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood your problem, you're trying to notify user whenever he/she gets gold. Now assuming you're passing the new value for Gold to the function your code should be something like:

```
private void GoldNotification(int newGold)
{
    var oldGold = Client.Player.Gold;

    if (newGold != -1 && newGold > oldGold) 
    //they've got gold. prceed to notify
}
```

But if you want the process to be automated, you could use events for this. You could implement Gold as a property and fire an event whenever its value changes.

Again, I'm not 100% sure what exactly you are trying to achieve but hopefully this'll be helpful.